# Laravel Ardent is not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ardent

I'm trying to submit updates to items in the Items model. However, Ardent never actually performs the updates when the update method receives them but doesn't throw an error:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

    if ($item->save()) {
        return Redirect::back()->with('message', "Item #$id updated!");
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($item->errors());
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my controller logic here?

Comment: Where are you actually changing values of your $item?

Comment: First time trying Ardent. I thought it actually pulled that from Input automatically. No?

Comment: I don't think Ardent is that magical ;) https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#automatically-hydrate-ardent-entities

Comment: I was hopeful. :/ So what is the cleanest way to pass the input data to Ardent to validate?

Comment: I haven't used hydration myself, but it looks like you would only need to set those variables ($autoHydrateEntityFromInput and $forceEntityHydrationFromInput) properly to get the behavior you expect.

Comment: @tomzx That was the problem! Totally missed that part of the docs about adding the autohydration for updates to my model. Thanks! Will you put that as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to set those variables

```
class Item extends \LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent {
    // hydrates on new entries' validation
    public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;    
    // hydrates whenever validation is called
    public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true; 
}
```

properly to get the behavior you expect.

Source: https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#automatically-hydrate-ardent-entities